# Parsing JSON data in PHP file using Javascript

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have seen some other posts in Stackoverflow which were related. Tried that code but it did not work out for me.

actually i have a database with 2 images of an actress in my MYSQL database. I am generating JSON data using PHP and it works fine.

[Link for JSON data](http://chipap.com/apps/nazriya_nazim/test1.php)

I am trying to parse it with Javascript as shown in this fiddle

[Direct Parsing Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rGKGV/)

```
var json = [{
    "id": "1",
    "url": "http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/J8yqh3y.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "url": "http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/WNx9i2c.jpg"
}];
var nazriya = json;
$.each(nazriya, function (index, nazriya_nazim) {
    $('#url-list').append('<li>' +
        '<h4>' + nazriya_nazim.url + '</h4>' +
        '</li>');
});
```

and it works fine.

But if i try to parse it from my PHP file located in my domain. It does not display anything. It shows blank page.

[FIDDLE Link : Parsing JSON data on PHP File](http://jsfiddle.net/dj8LR/)

```
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
url: "http://chipap.com/apps/nazriya_nazim/test1.php",
success: function (data) {
    alert("1");
    //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(idata);
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(json, function (index, nazriya) {
        $('#url-list').append('<li>' +
            '<h4>' + nazriya.url + '</h4>' +
            '</li>');
    });
}
```

I did not write all these code on my own. Browsed Stack and found solutions. But stuck up at the last step (parsing from a PHP file located in my server).

As said by @DaGLiMiOuX tried it in a separate HTML document.

```
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "http://chipap.com/apps/nazriya_nazim/test1.php",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("1");
        var json = data;
        $.each(data, function (index, nazriya) {
            $('#url-list').append('<li>' +
                '<h4>' + nazriya.url + '</h4>' +
                '</li>');
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorText) {
        alert('Status code: ' + jqXHR.status +
              '\nStatus text: ' + status + '\nError thrown: ' + errorText);
    }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="url-list"></ul>
</body>
```

Now also it shows the same error.

Comment: Do not use `JSON.parse`. The data that you are gonna recieve into your success function (`data`) it will be an object already.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX I am new to this JSON, Could you please be a bit more specific.

Comment: Of course. You got `var json = JSON.parse(data);`. You must set it `var json = data;`, but you already have `data`, so this is not needed. Just call in your `$.each(json, function (index, nazriya)` your `data` variable like this `$.each(data, function (index, nazriya)` Try and report, please. This should work.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX Still no change. Check Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dj8LR/2/

Changed line 6 and 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client side specified the jsonpcallback as below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "http://chipap.com/apps/nazriya_nazim/test1.php",


    jsonpCallback: function(data){
        alert('generate a specified jsonp callback');
        return "jsonpCall";
    },  


    success: function (data) {
        alert("1");
        var json = data;
        $.each(data, function (index, nazriya) {
            $('#url-list').append('<li>' +
                '<h4>' + nazriya.url + '</h4>' +
                '</li>');
        });
     },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorText) {
        alert('Status code: ' + jqXHR.status +
          '\nStatus text: ' + status + '\nError thrown: ' + errorText);
    }
```

});

In http://chipap.com/apps/nazriya_nazim/test1.php

```
<?php 
   $callback = $_GET["callback"]; // return  "jsonpCall" that was specified in    jsonpCallback ajax with jsonp

   $json = '[{"id":"1","url":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/J8yqh3y.jpg"},{"id":"2","url":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/WNx9i2c.jpg"}]' ;

   echo $callback.'('. $json.')' ;
 ?>
```

You can understand much better about jsonp at at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

http://jsfiddle.net/channainfo/wn5bz/

Comment: am acutally not directly entering the JSON values. I am getting them from my MYSQL DB

Answer (score 0):

1) that's just an extract of a code, not a compiling function. The complete code would be

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "http://chipap.com/apps/nazriya_nazim/test1.php",
  success: function (obj) {
    alert("1");
    $.each(obj, function (index, nazriya) {
        $('#url-list').append('<li>' +
            '<h4>' + nazriya.url + '</h4>' +
            '</li>');
    });
   }
});
```

2) you need to import jQuery (you don't do it in the fiddle)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dj8LR/1/

added your code to the fiddle. It still doesnt display anything.

Answer (score 0):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://chipap.com/apps/nazriya_nazim/test1.php. Origin
>   http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

You have to handle **ALWAYS** posible errors.

Check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dj8LR/4/)**.

This should work, but you got Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. This is caused because your `dataType` was incorrect. Try this configuration for your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "http://chipap.com/apps/nazriya_nazim/test1.php",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("1");
        var json = data;
        $.each(data, function (index, nazriya) {
            $('#url-list').append('<li>' +
                '<h4>' + nazriya.url + '</h4>' +
                '</li>');
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorText) {
        alert('Status code: ' + jqXHR.status +
              '\nStatus text: ' + status + '\nError thrown: ' + errorText);
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** You get in the demo an alert as if it were an **error**, but your status code is `200` (check **[status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)**). Try it in your project. Maybe JsFiddle it's not allowing to return data from external servers.

Comment: I did try the same in an html document for my project. It does not show error. As well as it shows a blank page.

Comment: @harishannam Instead to add `$('#url-list')...` in your success function, add `alert(data.url)` and report if it shows something or not

Comment: @harishannam I linked you a reference to Wikipedia about status codes. `200` is not an error code, it's a succesful code (`OK`). It means that your request was successful and it should return your data into your `success` function. Did you set into your php file `json_encode($data)` or whatever data/variable you want to return? Also, I've noticed that you are returning an object array. My last comment was not correct, use: `alert(JSON.parse(data)[0].url);` or `alert(data[0].url);` I'm not sure right now who is correct. You should specify things like that.

Comment: Its little complicated with JSON i suppose. planning to go with XML for my project.

Comment: @harishannam JSON it's easy, but you need to know how to work with it before you try to do something. Sorry, I tried to do my best. Hope you will find a solution even in JSON or XML.